Unable to use cloudMapId with Google Maps on IOS with Flutter
I am struggling to use a custom cloud id style with Google Maps package in flutter for IOS. I did not bother to see if the Android version was working, but I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.
I did the following so far

created a custom map style in the google console
associated a map id for iOS in the google console
set minimum version of my project to iOS14 (read somewhere that it was needed)
added the cloudMapId argument to my GoogleMap widget

I can see in google console a number of API calls is increasing, however the map on screen remains the default one.
Help appreciated. Thx!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Not much code to share - I am using google_maps_flutter from pub.dev. The GoogleMap object has a parameter called cloudMapId that takes a string.  I created the map id from the google console and associated the id to IOS. I wonder if I am missing something, but my custom map, with fewer details is not loaded on iOS.

Have you checked also if it is working fine with Android?

@Berbs, i had similar experience with you, what fix me was updating my Podfile. Please see the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/versions#cocoapods. Hope it can help you as well
